# How can I restrict whole page to re-render in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, use-state

I have js file which contains data that I am rendering on the page using `useState`. I have a button `Display` which uses `fetch API` to get more data and display below the existing data.

I would like to display `Loading` when `Display button` is clicked till data arrives.

Problem is whole page is re rendered with `Loading`. I would like to display data that I am getting from js file as it is and just display `Loading` below `Display` button till I get more data from API

```
 const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);


  if (isLoading) {
    return <h2>Loading..</h2>;
  }
```

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch(fetchDataUrl);
    const data = await response.json();
    setIsLoading(false);
    setMoreData(data.datas);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const Component = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const fetchData = () => {
         setIsLoading(true)
         fetch(someUrl)
            .then(data => {
                setData(data)
                setIsLoading(false)
         });
    }
    return (
    <> 
        {yourData.map((data) => <IdkMaybeItsSomeComponent data={data}>}

        { isLoading  
          ? <h2>Loading...</h2> 
          : <button onClick={fetchData}>Get More Data</button> }
    </>
    )
}
```

How about something like that? Only showing the loading at the bottom when you are currently loading data.

Comment: Where should I change `isLoading` to true?

Comment: @ParitoshM when you start loading the data? I edited to give a little more of an example.